# Import tab seperated text data in R with "unequal" number of tabs

Tags: r

I need to import data from a tab separated text file to R. The issue is that the number of tabs in the data file in each record are different. The data looks like this (Note: "->" indicates a Tab, {LF} indicated end of line (Line Feed) - NOTE the number of tabs is different in each record and variables are at different places - Header row has only 7 variables, but Record 3 has values from D13 thru D21 i.e., 9 values):

```
V1 -> V2 -> V3 -> V4 -> V5-> V6 -> V7 {LF}
D1 -> D2 -> D3 -> D4 -> D5-> D6 -> {LF}
D7 -> D8 -> D9 -> D10 -> -> D12 {LF}
D13 -> D14 -> D15 -> D16 -> D17-> D18 -> D19 -> D20 -> D21 {LF}
```

How do I read it so that I get something like this (Keeping in mind that maximum number of variables are 9, NOT 7 as indicated in Header row):

```
V1 -> V2 -> V3 -> V4 -> V5-> V6 -> V7 -> V8 -> V9 {LF}
D1 -> D2 -> D3 -> D4 -> D5-> D6 ->    -> NA -> NA {LF}
D7 -> D8 -> D9 -> D10 ->  -> D12 ->NA -> NA -> NA {LF}
D13 -> D14 -> D15 -> D16 -> D17-> D18 -> D19 -> D20 -> D21 {LF}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your data itself contains a header row V1 to V9. If yes skip that line and Let R generate column vector of its own and you can supply a column vector of length 9 separately later.

To read rows of unequal length use something like this. Lets suppose data is stored in a data.txt in the given form

Data :

```
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
D7  D8  D9  D10     D12
D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D20 D21
```

RScript:

```
data<-read.table("data.txt",sep = "\t",fill = TRUE)
```

This "fill" param will pad for the missing values and will give output as :

Output:

```
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9
1  D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6            
2  D7  D8  D9 D10     D12            
3 D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D20 D21
```

See how header vector is generated automatically.

If your data unnecessarily contains row vector you skip it using "skip" param.

Let's say :

Data :

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
D7  D8  D9  D10     D12
D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D20 D21
```

RScript :

```
data<-read.table("data.txt",sep = "\t",fill = TRUE,skip = 1)
```

Output will be same as above.

You can add a column vector as you desired later.

For e.g. you want column names as :

```
"C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "C8" "C9"
```

Do something like this :

```
custom_colnames<-c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9")
colnames(data)<-custom_colnames
```

Comment: what is it that you exactly need. Is my answer not the solution to your question. Would you like to elaborate your question again then?

Comment: Thanks, you got the question right. But I'm still stuck. I tried this:
    
    data<- read.table("file_path/file_name", sep="\t",fill=T,skip=1)

What it leads to is that some records get broken and overflow to the next line. Output is like this:
    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6
    D7  D8  D9  D10     D12
    D13 D14 D15 D16 D17 D18 D19 D20 
    D21

(NOTE: D21 was part of third row - notice it appears as fourth record). Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Yes looks like you are doing something wrong. Can you ensure that seperator between D20 and D21 is exactly one tab and not a new line feed, only a line feed will push data to the next row. By seeing your comment I cant see the actual output. Can you edit you original question static trying this script produces this result and post the result as a proper formatted output.

Comment: Sincere thanks for your expert help, effort and time. Yes, I opened the file in Notepad++ and see that the file indeed is correct - the {LF} character is AFTER D21 and there is indeed just a tab between D20 and D21. If I open it in SPSS Modler or SAS E Miner, the file "looks" ok. Unsure what can be the issue...Thanks again. Any thoughts are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: Can i have a look at your file. Mail me at dhawalkapil@gmail.com